# posix_spawn a shell script, trouble passing arguments

Tags: c++, shell, posix

I need a to be able to use some of the process control facilities provided by posix_spawn() like suspend/resume/kill etc, something that system() does not give me. 
So use the following call to posix_spawn() to launch a shell script from a c++ program:

```
 int result = posix_spawn(&spawnedPid, processExecutable, 0, 0, argumentList, 0);
```

where processExecutable is "foo.sh" and argumentList is {"bar",0,0,0}; The process foo.sh starts up just fine, except for the argumentList part. If I do something like "echo $1" in foo.sh, I get an empty string. If I launch a binary the same way, the arguments are just fine and I can reach them via argv[]. Is there anything I should be doing differently in order to pass arguments to foo.sh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me, the argumentList parameter of posix_spawn() is 0-based so echo $1 actually outputs argumentList[1], which is, naturally, set to 0. Case closed.